# How do I test using the ipad simulator in Cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I used the following command to run my game in the iphone simulator and it works great (takes a while to compile, but that's ok. I'm building for web first anyways)

```
 cocos run -p ios
```

I want to be able to test using the ipad simulator and preferably my own ipad, but I'm unsure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to change the target device in XCode under product>destination in the top menu options.

I ran the project, and although it does take a very long time, it well eventually compile and run on the device you choose.

I'd still prefer there to be a cmdline way to change the device, but as long as I can do it one way or another, then i can move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that. The command you mentioned is a Python script which, behind the scenes, starts iOS Simulator in default mode, and that's iPhone. There is currently no way to parameterize it so that it starts with iPad.

Comment: There must be some way to run it on a device or ipad simulator. I want to continue developing in my own environment, but if I opened the project in cocos studio or something, then maybe I could test with ipad there?

Comment: Why can't you simply open the project in Xcode then? You can still continue developing in your own environment, and use Xcode only to run it on device and simulator.

Comment: I tried opening the project file in the frameworks folder and it didn't give me an option to choose the device to run on. Also there are multiple projects in the project.

Comment: You'll have to provide some more information before this can be solved. Where exactly is this frameworks folder? What is the path leading to it? What is its exact name? Also, you speak of multiple projects? Where are they and what are their names?